# React HTML table

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I am currently trying to make a HTML table work in React, but something isn't going the way it should. I do get a render output but with the error of: `<tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>`.

I tried to find it online, but the technique I am using doesn't seem to be used that often, so if I am doing that wrong, please enlighten me.
Thank you in advance!

```js
getTableContent = (arr) => {
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach(function (item, i) {
        result.push(
            <table key={item.productType}>
                <thead>{item.productType}</thead>
                <tbody>
                    {item.contents.forEach(function (nextItem, j) {
                        result.push(
                            <tr key={nextItem.type}>
                                <td>{nextItem.type}</td>
                                <td>{nextItem.count}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            );
    });
    return result;
};

render() {
    return (
            <div>{this.getTableContent(productSpecification)}</div>
    );
}
```

The data looks as follows:

```js
const productSpecification = [
    {
        productType: "abc", contents: [
            {type: "abc", count: 231},
            {type: "abc", count: 56},
            {type: "abc", count: 54},
            {type: "abc", count: 544},
            {type: "abc", count: 54},
            {type: "abc", count: 564},
            {type: "abc", count: 4},
            {type: "abc", count: 4564},
            {type: "abc", count: 4531},
            {type: "abc", count: 234},
            {type: "abc", count: 57},
            {type: "abc", count: 7}
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: This probably isn't the cause of your problem, but won't your table rows all have the same `key`? You could use `j` as a unique key (perhaps you meant to and that's why `j` exists?).

Comment: I didnt get the error that a key is a duplicate, but still, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of pushing to `array` you can try return `jsx` from `function` Try this.

```js
getTableContent = (arr) => {
    const iterateItem = (item) => {
       return item.map(function (nextItem, j) {
         return (
            <tr key={nextItem.type}>
               <td>{nextItem.type}</td>
               <td>{nextItem.count}</td>
            </tr>
         );
       })
    }
    return arr.map(function (item, i) {
        return (
            <table key={item.productType}>
            <thead>{item.productType}</thead>
                <tbody>
                    {iterateItem(item.contents)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    });
};

render() {
    return (
            <div>{this.getTableContent(productSpecification)}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: For an arrow function only with a return statement you can write it shorter - `const iterateItem = item => item.map(function(){...});`, i.e. no `return` and additional braces :)

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to return `tr` rows:

```js
{item.contents.forEach(function (nextItem, j) {
    result.push(
        <tr key={nextItem.type}>
            <td>{nextItem.type}</td>
            <td>{nextItem.count}</td>
        </tr>
    )
})}
```

But in fact it modifies the `result` variable, pushing the `tr`s to it instead of returning them. This causes the `result` variable to be full of both `table`s and `tr`s. You should *return* the `tr`s in `map`, not push them to `result` in a `forEach`:

```js
{item.contents.map(function (nextItem, j) {
    return (
        <tr key={nextItem.type}>
            <td>{nextItem.type}</td>
            <td>{nextItem.count}</td>
        </tr>
    )
})}
```

Comment: Are you thinking of `map`?

Comment: Alright, I see where I went wrong there. Cheers for that, but your edit doesnt seems to work out. Its all empty.

Comment: @stone yes, I was thinking of it as map.

Comment: @Wesselink yeah sorry I didn't pay enough attention. Replace foreach with map to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add opening and closing `<tbody>` tags, like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There already are open and close tags, see the code above. But thank you for your input!